# How to do "pip install -e ." in VS 2017 Python environment?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I need to do a "pip install -e ." from a current directory to install a Python package into the VS 2017 Python environment.

I know how to do this from the Python environment available in the normal command prompt. But, how do I do this into the Python environment that is installed with VS 2017?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

First, the version of Python installed by Visual Studio 2017 is just regular Python. So from a command prompt you can type `py.exe -m pip install -e .` (optionally including a version number as `py.exe -3.6 -m pip ...`) to run any commands with it as you normally would.

(But note that Visual Studio installs Python for all users, which means you may need to use an administrator command prompt or a virtual environment.)

Second, if you're in Visual Studio, you can use the regular "Install package" dialog. When searching for a package, the first item in the list is going to execute exactly what you type. You'll need to use the full path rather than `.`, but otherwise you can type `-e <path>` in there and click the first result:

[image: Python Environments window in Visual Studio 2017 showing a special <code>pip install</code> command]

Comment: Just for clarity, the text in the image reads "Run command: pip install ..." as of a recent change. Previously it was not as clear that it would treat the search field as the entire command.

Comment: Thanks! Why isn "python" and "pip" available as regular commands from the command prompt like in other Python installations? I find this a bit confusing that you have to type "py.exe".

Comment: You can modify your `PATH` variable to make them available. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do that. It isn't the default because it becomes a real problem when programs change it - especially when they conflict with each other. `py.exe` is much safer, though it's a shame it isn't more consistent.